# How to add a web font using the asset-pipeline?

Tags: php, laravel, asset-pipeline

I would like to add google web font using asset-pipeline. I know how to add fonts via files, but I don't know how to add something like this

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

via asset-pipeline. I have only found tutorials for adding static fonts via files.

Does anyone know what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would want to add this to a master.blade.php (something all blade templates will extend)

```
Asset::add('google-font', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700');
```

[Reference Laravel Forum](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=3963)

Answer (score 0):

there is the simple way to do it

```
{{ HTML::style('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display') }}
```